# How can I save a playlist to a MP3 player using Foobar2000?

Tags: mp3, media-player, foobar2000, music-management

I am using [Foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org) but have not been able to figure out how to generate a valid playlist that an MP3 player can use.

For example, I have SanDisk Clip Jam MP3 player. It has 5 folders on it, two of which are `Music` and `Playlists`. I have copied all my MP3 music files into the `Music` folder, and that seems to be working. For example, the song with the file name `01 - Carry on Wayward Son.mp3` shows up as "Carry on Wayward Son" in the main "Music" list on the player's LCD screen.

The problem is that I tried to save a playlist from Foobar2000 to the player and it is not recognizing. Foobar can save playlists in 3 different formats (fpl, m3u, and m3u8). When I open up the files that it creates, it has the full path name to the song ON MY COMPUTER, not a relative pathname. So, for example, there are entries in the playlist file like `K:\music\rock\01 - Carry on Wayward Son.mp3`. So, possibly the player is confused by the pathname? I don't know.

When I open the "Playlist Option" on the player, it shows the name of my playlist file, but then says it is "empty".

Comment: Foobar tries to use portable paths whenever possible. When you save the playlist and select a location for it, you should select the same drive as where your music files are. I usually save them in my root music folder. I just double checked and I see relative paths in my playlist files

Answer (score 0):

Mp3 player will not have same paths and files won't be there, in your example you should open in notepad (or any text editor) and Replace all instances of "K:\music\rock\" to the correct mp3 player path.  (Try to make a playlist on your mp3 player and obtain it's structure from there)